# Convert Class Member to String with Typescript in Current Class

Tags: typescript

To convert class member name to string,

I utilize the following function. However in the example below, we always have to write the name of the Current Component.

How to modify the export function, so its always pointing to the current class its in, without having to retype the class?

**Function:**

```
export function nameof<T>(key: keyof T, instance?: T): keyof T {
    return key;
}
```

**Example Use:**

```
nameof<SampleComponent>('productInput')
```

Resource: https://www.meziantou.net/typescript-nameof-operator-equivalent.htm

Comment: What does this have to do with Angular?

Comment: well angular has its own modifications on typescript sometimes, pipe, routing, etc syntax

Comment: Angular doesn't modify TypeScript; nor is TypeScript a language which can be "modified" outside the `tsconfig` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the article you linked yourself gives the answer:

> However, this is not possible in TypeScript yet.

The language simply doesn't support automatically specifying a generic parameter based on the fact that the function has been called in the class.

Comment: well article says there is no official library for nameof, you can create your own one, however it does not specifically say if a new function can be directed toward its own class